Impossible to create account on wordpress.org with email on free.fr
One of my clients have tried to create an account on wordpress.org but does not receive the mail to activate the account. He uses an email on free.fr
I have myself tested the recover the password on wordpress.org for a different account also with an email adress on free.fr, but no mail is received. So I assume that free.fr is blacklisted at wordpress.org. Does anybody know if this problem can be fixed?

Have you tried creating account with some other email id? Check this once whether you face the same issue or not?
Apart from this, one solution that you can try is adding the WordPress.org email addresses (e.g., noreply@wordpress.org) to the whitelist or safe sender list in the free.fr email settings.

Thanks for these ideas, but no. I have checked and emails for "recover password" work fine with other email addresses. On the free.fr account the SPAM filter is switched off and wordpress@wordpress.org (which is the sender of recovery emails) is in the address book.
